# variable not defined even after setting as global (Python) + How do I approach such cases?

Tags: python, recursion, nameerror

I have a recursive function which computes some answer at the end and I have to store the maximum of these temporary answers and return it.

The code is as follows.
*(If you know this, I am not worried about Kadane's Algorithm, I wanted to know how to get this done)*

```
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        
        ans = nums[0]
        
        def helper(n):
            
            global ans

            if(n == 1):
                return nums[0]
            
            temp = max(nums[n-1], nums[n-1]+helper(n-1))
            
            ans = max(ans, temp) ### how do I do this? ###
            
            return temp
        
        helper(len(nums))
        return ans
```

The error I get is:
`NameError: name 'ans' is not defined`

How do I store the maximum value and return it in such cases? Since this doesn't work.

Comment: Because there is no global `ans` when you first try to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for the `nonlocal` keyword!
This keyword allows you to refer to the `ans` variable in the enclosing function.

Solution (simply replace `global` with `nonlocal`):

```
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        
        ans = nums[0]
        
        def helper(n):
            
            nonlocal ans

            if(n == 1):
                return nums[0]
            
            temp = max(nums[n-1], nums[n-1]+helper(n-1))
            
            ans = max(ans, temp) ### how do I do this? ###
            
            return temp
        
        helper(len(nums))
        return ans
```

Comment: "This keyword allows you to refer to the ans variable in the enclosing function." It allows you to *assign* to it, you can always merely refer to it. But yes, this is much better than using a global variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a global in the same function as the variable declaration itself because right now you are trying to set a global for a variable that is outside of the nested function's scope.

The following code should work:

```
class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        
    global ans
    ans = nums[0]
    
    def helper(n):
        
        global ans
        if(n == 1):
            return nums[0]
        
        temp = max(nums[n-1], nums[n-1]+helper(n-1))
        
        ans = max(ans, temp) ### how do I do this? ###
        
        return temp
    
    helper(len(nums))
    return and
```

do keep in mind you must put `global ans` not just when you define the variable, but in every function that you wish to assign to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `global ans` twice in the first function and in the second.
with your code:

```
class Solution:
def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:

    global ans

    ans = nums[0]
    
    def helper(n):
        
        global ans

        if(n == 1):
            return nums[0]
        
        temp = max(nums[n-1], nums[n-1]+helper(n-1))
        
        ans = max(ans, temp) ### how do I do this? ###
        
        return temp
    
    helper(len(nums))
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

many have already answered You need to use nonlocal instead of global. let me just try to explain why you need to do so.

"nonlocal" means that a variable is "neither local nor global", i.e, the variable is from an enclosing namespace (typically from an outer function of a nested function as it happens to be your case)

To explain the difference between nonlocal and global I would say that the nonlocal variable must have been already bound in the enclosing namespace (otherwise a syntax error will be raised) while a global declaration in a local scope does not require the variable to be pre-bound (it will create a new binding in the global namespace if the variable is not pre-bound).